# in metaworks, when I use TreeFace.ejs, Error message 'Please add @Name for the nameField to...' in metaworks3 application

Tags: ejs

Eventhough I have added @Name field in the domain class, the error message that the TreeFace.ejs (actually TreeNodeFace.ejs) couldn't find the Name field.

Answer (score 0):

There must be getter and setters, I found i have missed defining the setter in this case:

```
@Name
@Face(displayName = "name")
public String getDisplayName() {
    return displayName
}
```

after adding setDisplayName(String dispName), the error has been gone.